# How to capture a certain group of lines using perl regex?

Tags: perl

How to remove a trailing blank space in a regex substitution?

Here the Data

```
              __Data__
              Test - results 
              dkdkdkdkdkdkdkdkdkkkdkd
              slsldldldldldldldldldll
              Information
              ddkdkdkeieieieieieieiei
              eieieieieieieieieieieiei
              Test - summary
              dkdkdkdkdkdkdkdkkdkdkdk
              dkdkdkdkdkdkdkdkdkdkdkk
```

What I would like to remove these lines shown above:

```
              Information
              ddkdkdkeieieieieieieiei
              eieieieieieieieieieieiei
```

My attempt using regex expression

```
           $/ = "__Data__";

           $_ =~ s/^(Test.*[^\n]+)\n(Information.*[^\n]+)\n(Test.*Summary[^\n]+)/$1$3/ms;
              print $_
```

The input of the data is the same as the output. In other words, nothing changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not this:

```
while (<DATA>) {
    if ( m/^Information/..m/^Test/ ) {
        next unless m/^Test/;
    }
    s{\s+$}{};
    print "$_\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to remove the information section use

```
$s =~ s/Information.*Test/Test/s;
```

if $s contains the data you gave then the following is returned

```
Test - results 
dkdkdkdkdkdkdkdkdkkkdkd
slsldldldldldldldldldll
Test - summary
dkdkdkdkdkdkdkdkkdkdkdk
dkdkdkdkdkdkdkdkdkdkdkk
```

If you want the information only then use

```
$s =~ s/(.*?)(Information.*?)(Test.*)/$2/s;
```

In both cases notice the the "s" at the end of the substitution, that flag allows it to process multiple lines.